# How to deal with missing value error in R when using ugarchfit?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a GARCH model but seem to be getting this error repetitively. Could someone please help me solve it?

````
Error in if (mean(data) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example of your data and code that reproduces the error? Looks like you have `NA` while you should only have `TRUE` or `FALSE` values

Comment: Sure! so the code I am using is ```m <- ugarchfit(data = return, spec = s)```

Comment: As for the data > tail(return[-1])
           RELIANCE.NS.Close
2021-05-17       0.011897964
2021-05-18       0.014079106
2021-05-19       0.004577629
2021-05-20      -0.005833617
2021-05-21       0.008638070
2021-05-24      -0.008439252

Comment: It's essentially stock price returns and certain values are producing NA